# Removing/ignoring NA values in an if loop

Tags: r, if-statement, na

So I have this simple if loop

```
chick<-lapply(1:length(t),function(i){
if(t[[i]]<0.01){
chick=1
}else 0 
})
```

So basically when t<0.01 it print outs 1 if not it prints 0 but there are times when I have data that has NA values like the one below....how can I assign the NA values 0 as well coz I'll get an error similar to this if I dont:

```
Error in if (t[[i]] < 0.01) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here is a sample output from data called 't'

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] 0.01
```

thanks again

Comment: If you don't mind running a command just before `lapply`, it'll be **much** more efficient to just do `t[ is.na(t) ] <- 0` rather than do it inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

use `is.na`

```
if(t[!is.na(t)][[i]]<0.01) ...
```

---

More importatnly though, since you are assigning to `chick`, do not try to also assign inside your `lapply` (or similar) statement.  It will give you results different from what you are expecting.  Instead try

```
chick <- lapply(1:length(t),function(i)  
  if(t[!is.na(t)][[i]]<0.01)  1  else 0 
)
```

Or better yet, use ifelse.

```
chick <- ifelse(t[!is.na(t)] < 0.01, 1, 0)
```

If you want `chick` to be the same length as `t`, then use the '|' operator in ifelse. as suggested by NPE (but use single `|` not `||` in `ifelse`)

Answer (score 0):

The following with check whether `t[[i]]` is either `NA` or less than `0.01`:

```
if (is.na(t[[i]]) || t[[i]] < 0.01) {
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use...

```
chick <- numeric( length(t) )
chick[ t < 0.01 ] <- 1
```

... and avoid loops and checking for NA altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this (invert the test and return 0 for the complementary test as well as for NA):

```
 chick <- ifelse(is.na(t)|t>=0.01, 0, 1)
```

This should work because FALSE|NA will return FALSE. See the ?Logic page. It's also more efficient that looping with `lapply`. I suppose if you need the results in list format you could eitehr do as.list to the results or use:

```
     if( is.na(t) || t>=0.01 ) { 0 }else{ 1 }
```